# Get Full name from Windows Authentication in ASP.Net BLL class

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Trying to figure out how to get the current User's Full Name as entered in Active Directory from a BLL class in my ASP.Net application.  So far I have:

```
   public static string Username
    {
        get
        {
            var name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            if (name.Contains("\\"))
            {
                var start = name.IndexOf("\\");

                if (name.Length > start)
                {
                    name = name.Substring(start + 1);
                }
            }

            return name;
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that this will return the Username, but I am also in need of the Full Name.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) ...

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher( new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://YourDomain") );
search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=UserNameHere)"; // put the identity name here
var res  = search.FindOne();
var name = res["displayName"]; // I believe this is the right property
```

Comment: Noooooes... but I don't wanna actually query AD!